# Trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal, lobemo-scribe-systemd

Tags: plutus, cabal, build, ubuntu

2 days stucked with this (running on Ubuntu):

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01]$ cabal build 
Warning: Requested index-state 2021-10-20T00:00:00Z is newer than 'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2021-10-19T23:39:06Z).
Resolving dependencies... cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: Win32-network-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: base-4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0 (dependency of Win32-network)
[__2] trying: lobemo-scribe-systemd-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__3] next goal: libsystemd-journal (dependency of lobemo-scribe-systemd)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.5 (conflict: pkg-config package libsystemd>=209, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.4 (conflict: base==4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0, libsystemd-journal => base>=4.6 && <4.13)
[__3] skipping: libsystemd-journal-1.4.3, libsystemd-journal-1.4.2, libsystemd-journal-1.4.1, libsystemd-journal-1.4.0, libsystemd-journal-1.3.4, libsystemd-journal-1.3.3, libsystemd-journal-1.3.1, libsystemd-journal-1.3.0, libsystemd-journal-1.2.0, libsystemd-journal-1.1.0, libsystemd-journal-1.0.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the previous version to fail: excludes 'base' version 4.14.1.0)
[__3] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, libsystemd-journal, lobemo-scribe-systemd) After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal, lobemo-scribe-systemd, Win32-network Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal, lobemo-scribe-systemd

Comment: In my case, I needed to put a base dependency version constraint in my cabal file: `base ^>=4.14.1.0`.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when running nix-shell from the plutus repository. To fix I exited that nix-shell, navigated to plutus-apps repository, and checked out the appropriate hash from the cabal.project file found in the cabal.project file. Then ran nix-shell from plutus-apps instead of plutus.

```
source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
  tag: 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a
```

1. `$> cd <projects-dir>/plutus-apps`
2. `$> git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a`
3. `$> nix-shell`
4. `$> cd ../plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01`
5. `$> cabal repl`

Answer (score 0):

the coresponding version for you can find there

$cd ~/code/haskell/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01/
$less cabal.project

and there is a tag with right version

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).